# Regex find / replace for key/value pairs in a string

Tags: java, regex, replace, key-value

I'm trying to solve a problem with taking 'userData' that contains possible substitute-able parameters that fit a regex ${parameter} and skip over other forms like $parameter cause its missing the squiggle brackets. I'm also tracking replaceable successful matches that it can find in the map of keys (kvPairs). I want to just warn if this is the case.

In the userData string I also have a parameter that gets substituted with a value that contains a match. I would've thought the match positionally would not be evaluated but it throws an exception:

In general, how's my approach? can I improve upon it at all?

```
exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No group with name {myVariable}
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:849)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceFirst(Matcher.java:1004)
    at 
utils.Regex.getKeyValueSubstitutedUserData(Regex.java:36)
    at utils.Regex.main(Regex.java:77)
```

I may decide to I block this. But I'm wondering what the heck this is failing for. Is it resetting the position and re-evaluating the match?

```
package Utils;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex {

   public Regex() {}

   private String getKeyValueSubstitutedUserData(Map<String, String> kvPairs, String userData) {

       String patternToFind = "(\\$\\{)(.+?)(\\})";
       Pattern regex = Pattern.compile( patternToFind );

       Matcher match = regex.matcher( userData );
       Set<String> missingKeys = new LinkedHashSet<>();
       while ( match.find()) {

           String key2 = match.group(2);

           if ( key2 != null ) {

              String value = kvPairs.get( key2 );

              if ( value != null ) {
                  userData = match.replaceFirst( value );
                  match.reset( userData );
              }
              else {
                  // Found a missing variable
                  missingKeys.add( key2 );
              }
          }
      }


      return userData;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      Regex regexUtil = new Regex();

      Map<String, String> kvPairs = new HashMap<> ();
      kvPairs.put( "LOCALHOSTIP", "10.234.158.5" );
      kvPairs.put( "METADATA_POLL_FREQ" , "60");
      kvPairs.put( "router1_eth0_cidr" , "10.234.158.0/24");
      kvPairs.put( "router1_eth0_gateway" , "10.234.158.1");
      kvPairs.put( "router1_eth0_mac_addresss" , "fa:16:3e:6f:4a:c3");
      kvPairs.put( "EVENT_TYPE" , "BOOT");
      kvPairs.put( "testFIP" , "_FIP_router_eth0");
      kvPairs.put( "METADATA_TIMESTAMP" , "1");
      kvPairs.put( "vnfInstanceNumber" , "1");
      kvPairs.put( "TestFIPVIP" , "_FIP_VIP_router_eth0");
      kvPairs.put( "router1_eth0" , "10.234.158.5");
      kvPairs.put( "myVariable" , "193.167.1.1");
      kvPairs.put( "HOSTNAME" , "router1");
      kvPairs.put( "METADATA_SCRIPT" , "erg");
      kvPairs.put( "_FIP_router1_eth0" , "10.2.31.42");
      kvPairs.put( "LOCALHOST" , "router1");
      kvPairs.put( "testVIP" , "_VIP_router_eth0");
      kvPairs.put( "HOSTNAMEIP" , "10.234.158.5");
      kvPairs.put( "TestNesting" , "${myVariable}");

      String userData = "abcShell script \n${HOSTNAMEIP} blah blah \n ${\nrouter1_eth0_gateway} ${HOSTNAME} $HOSTNAME ${EVENT_TYPE} ${foobar} ${TestNesting} ${_FIP_router1_eth0}";

      regexUtil.getKeyValueSubstitutedUserData( kvPairs, userData);

    }
}
```

Comment: Who is Brian and why are you thanking him?

Comment: its me, I'm thanking those that answer me.

Comment: We don't really need that in problem description :) more info at [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: `${name}` can be used in replacement part to access content from named capturing group like `(?<name>:\\w+)`.